# In javax validator is there a way to not display @Size error if @NotBlank is already true

Tags: java, validation

Consider the following bean:

```
class A {

  @NotBlank(message="1")
  @Size(min = 3, message="2")
  @Size(max = 30, message="3")
  String name;
}
```

**message.properties**

```
1=Name cannot be blank
2=Name must be at least 3 characters
3=Name cannot be more than 30 characters
```

The issue is if name is blank two messages are shown, `@NotBlank` and `@Size(min=3)`.

I would like the `@Size` to be ignored if `@NotBlank` has fired, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Why have the `NotBlank` condition when that case is covered by your min `Size`?